# How to draw the editor's camera position in play mode Unreal?

Tags: camera, unreal

The blue camera that is drawn for the CameraComponent in the editor.

My intended usage is that when playing a third person template, ejecting from the pawn and then selecting it, will show the Camera debug asset instead of just the camera boom.

[image: Editor mode view]

So in the above picture of the editor mode, the camera attached to the pawn is visible.

[image: Play mode view]

Yet when in play mode. Ejecting from the pawn and selecting the pawn shows only the camera boom (the red line) and not the camera 'debug asset' used in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Edited with the correct answer:

I am starting with a fresh third person template project, and moving from there.

1. Select the ThirdPersonCharacter in the Editor Viewport
2. Click the blue Edit Blueprint button under the Details panel (below the World Outliner) and select Add or Edit Script, which opens the blueprint editor
3. If it's not already visible, click the Window tab at the top and make sure there is a checkmark near Components.
4. Select the FollowCamera component, which should open up the Details page on the right
5. Scroll down the details panel to the Events section, and click the big green plus sign next to On Component Activated
6. On the background next to the event node that was just added to the blueprint editor, right-click to open the context menu, and in there type Hidden.
7. Select the item labeled "Set Hidden In Game (FollowCamera)" and adjust the nodes so you can see it.
8. Drag the white bar with the Exec tooltip from the "On Component Activated" event over to the input for the "Set Hidden In Game" node.
9. Tick the lower right checkbox located in the "Set Hidden in Game" node labeled "Propagate to Children". The check box above it should remain unticked.
10. Save, compile and test your game. It should now display the blue camera when ejecting from the pawn.

Here is a picture of the configured nodes.

[image: nodes]

Thank you for the learning experience. I worked for Epic Games on the unreal engine geometry team and never once got the opportunity to play with the engine.

[image: tada]

Comment: Edited the question for clarity. I believe my question is more similar to the latter point you make. Apologies for lack of clarity in the first place.

Comment: Now I've edited the question for clarity would you mind removing the downvote?

Comment: @Natalo77 please do not make assumptions about which users gave you down-votes. If a user wants you to know their vote they will tell you in their post; if they choose not to then that  information is private. Generally speaking though, users who think your question is good enough to answer won't be the ones down-voting it (their answers lose some prominence if the question is hidden/put on hold, after all).

Comment: FWIW, I upvoted your question, friend. I have never downvoted, as I see that as more of a moderators job. I saw your -1 and thought that was a tad bit unfair, considering it took only a little guesswork to understand what you were asking.

Comment: With regard to your clarification, unfortunately, I still can't quite understand what you're attempting to accomplish. Is this not for use in a game, but rather to more clearly understand how the editor works? I.E. You want to be able to hop out of a third person template and see where the camera was at the time you hit the stop button? Or are you trying to hop into play mode and visualize the precise location of the Editor's Viewport camera (the one you fly around with to edit the level) prior to hitting play?

Comment: Apologies for the assumptions and bad etiquette, still slightly new to the site.

Comment: Added pictures for more clarification of question

Comment: No worries, I'm just here to help if I can.

Comment: I figured it out and will update my answer accordingly.